# Error in during Fix pack post-install configure

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

I am trying to install 8.0.0.11 Fix pack on z/OS WebSphere 8.0.0.0 and during "post-install configure" I get an error like this:

```
CRIMAF37550BFE ERROR: Error during "post-install configure" phase:
  CRIMAF37550BFE ERROR: Error executing "/bin/extattr" operation (status=2).
  See agent output log for more information: /InstallationManager/appdata/logs/native/20151011_1615.log
CRIMAD7EDE31W WARNING: com.ibm.ws.execute.iscdeploy.PostSessionActionISCDeployExecutor - getISCDeployCommand(): /usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/bin/iscdeploy.sh does not exist.
CRIMAD7EDE31W com.ibm.ws.execute.iscdeploy.PostSessionActionISCDeployExecutor - getISCDeployCommand(): /usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/bin/iscdeploy.sh does not exist.                                                                           
The 20151011_1615.log content is:

FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390-31/bbo3mvs: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390-31/bboboa: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390-31/bbocomm: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390-31/bbocorba: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390-31/bbolrt: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390-31/bboorb: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390-31/bbooxpxy: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390-31/bboras: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390-31/bborzls: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390-31/bbosec: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390-31/bbotots: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390-31/bboujfu: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390-31/bboujuu: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390-31/bbouph: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390-31/bboutil: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390-common/bboacall: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390x-64/bbg3mvs: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390x-64/bbgadapt: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390x-64/bbgboa: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390x-64/bbgcf: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390x-64/bbgcomm: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390x-64/bbgcorba: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390x-64/bbglrt: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390x-64/bbgorb: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390x-64/bbgoxpxy: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390x-64/bbgras: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390x-64/bbgrzls: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390x-64/bbgsec: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390x-64/bbgtots: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390x-64/bbguds: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390x-64/bbgujuu: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390x-64/bbgutil: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390x9-64/bbg3mvs: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390x9-64/bbgadapt: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390x9-64/bbgboa: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390x9-64/bbgcf: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390x9-64/bbgcomm: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390x9-64/bbgcorba: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390x9-64/bbglrt: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390x9-64/bbgorb: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390x9-64/bbgoxpxy: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390x9-64/bbgras: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390x9-64/bbgrzls: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390x9-64/bbgsec: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390x9-64/bbgtots: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390x9-64/bbguds: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390x9-64/bbgujuu: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
FOMF0303I /Z113/usr/lpp/zWebSphere/V8R0/lib/s390x9-64/bbgutil: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=092404C7
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See this link: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS2RWS_2.1.0/com.ibm.zsecure.doc_2.1/installation/srvr_setup_c2rzwini_probs.html

Do you have necessary read/write/execute permission?

Comment: Hi, I found this link too, bout I don’t know what FACILITY I should add.